# on thumbnail click pull up video in other div

Tags: jquery, css

I have two divs.  The first, #mainPlayer holds a large image.  The second, #videoThumbnails holds three images (.thumbnailOne, .thumnbailTwo, .thumbnailThree).  When a user clicks on one of the three images, I want a video to pull up in the #mainPlayer.  However I'm not sure of the best way to go about this:

My first thought is to have a hidden div with a  inside it, which is show inside #mainPlayer when one of the three images is clicked.  I'm not very good with jQuery, but the code would be something like this:

```
$(".thumbnailOne").click(function(){
 $("#mainPlayer).html(".hidden");
});
```

My other thought is to have #mainPlayer have three different hidden divs with s inside them.  Then when one of the images is clicked on, the corresponding div would be shown.

```
$(".thumbnailOne").click(function(){
  $('.hidden').css({"display:block"});
});
```

How would you suggest creating a script to cause the desired behavior?  Also, I understand JavaScript basics, but have very little understanding of jQuery and DOM manipulations, so any explanations would be appreciated!

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Medda86 mentioned, it would be helpful to see your html so we can see what exactly you're trying to accomplish. I have a slightly different alternative, depending on what you're looking for.

Take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6mgd1oz5/1/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="mainPlayer" data-activethumb="0">
    <p id="promptText">Please pick a video below</p>
    <div class="video" data-thumbnail="1">
        <h1>Video 1</h1>
        <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="video" data-thumbnail="2">
        <h1>Video 2</h1>
        <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="video" data-thumbnail="3">
        <h1>Video 3</h1>
        <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div><!-- End mainPlayer -->
<div id="videoThumbnails">
    <p> Select a video: </p>
    <div class="thumbnail" data-thumbnail="1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail" data-thumbnail="2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail" data-thumbnail="3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#mainPlayer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#mainPlayer p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

#videoThumbnails {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.video {
    display: none;
}

.thumbnail {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And finally, the JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // When a thumbnail is clicked
    $('.thumbnail').click(function() {
        // Store the thumbnail that was clicked
        var thumb = $(this).data('thumbnail');

        if ($('#mainPlayer').data('activethumb') == 0) { // If no video has been activated
            // Fade out the text since one was chosen
            $('#promptText').fadeOut(300, 0, function() {
                // Callback: fade in the video
                $('.video[data-thumbnail='+thumb+']').fadeTo(300, 1);

                // Change the active thumb on the video div
                $('#mainPlayer').data('activethumb', thumb);
            }); 
        } else if ($('#mainPlayer').data('activethumb') != thumb) { // If a current video is active, but not the one clicked
            $('.video').fadeOut(300, 0, function() {
                // Callback: Fade in the new video
                $('.video[data-thumbnail='+thumb+']').fadeTo(300, 1);

                // Change the active thumb on the video div
                $('#mainPlayer').data('activethumb', thumb);
            }); 
        }



    });

});
```

What I'm doing here is taking advantage of custom data attributes and using them to show or hide the video as needed, as well as to let me know if a video is already active, etc. I tried to comment everywhere that would be useful to you, however let me know if you are unsure of anything. It's a very basic example, but if that's the way you're thinking of going, you could certainly add quite a bit to it.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm going to take a look at how I would implement it.  I might have some follow up questions, but this makes the most sense so for.

Comment: Glad you like it! Definitely feel free to let me know if there are any questions along the way

Comment: @strasbal Loading every iframe on load is not very optimal. Loading iframe dynamically when requested is the way to go. Please check my example.

Comment: If there's only a small number of iframes being loaded, it wouldn't cause any issues whatsoever. If there were more and actually noticeable performance issues, the code could be slightly modified to pass iframe URLs and modify one existing one easily instead (through the use of a jquery object for example, or better yet, from a database)

Answer (score 0):

You have to share your html so we can have a look at it. If you need the video you have to add that html to the main div with the video url.

Here's an example I wrote for you in jsfiddle that uses youtube iframe.
http://jsfiddle.net/b6jtwndd/

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div id="mainPlayer"></div>

<div class="video-thumbnails">
    <a href="u-KqDVNowKU" title="Benny Benassi ft. Gary Go - Cinema">
        <img src="https://thethemefoundry.com/wp-content/themes/ttf-reloaded/images/single-theme/video-thumbnail.png" alt="Benny Benassi ft. Gary Go - Cinema">
    </a>

    <a href="Cix6xLpJS7w" title="Muse - Starlight">
        <img src="https://thethemefoundry.com/wp-content/themes/ttf-reloaded/images/single-theme/video-thumbnail.png" alt="Muse - Starlight">
    </a>

    <a href="qXavZYeXEc0" title="The four tops - I can't help myself">
        <img src="https://thethemefoundry.com/wp-content/themes/ttf-reloaded/images/single-theme/video-thumbnail.png" alt="The four tops - I can't help myself">
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#mainPlayer{
    width:720px;
    height:405px;
    background:#333;
    display:block;
}

#mainPlayer iframe{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.video-thumbnails{
    padding:10px 0;
}

.video-thumbnails img{
    width:100px;
    margin-right:10px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}

.video-thumbnails .active img{
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('.video-thumbnails a').click(function(){
    $('.video-thumbnails a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#mainPlayer').html('<iframe type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+$(this).attr('href')+'" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>');
    return false;
});
```

Hope that helps... sure you can edit it and use html5 video if you like.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'll take a look at the code and see how best to implement it!

Comment: @strasbal I added so that first video is preloaded by triggering a click, and I added an active video check as well over here http://jsfiddle.net/b6jtwndd/1/ Please let me know if this works for you. Cheers